# ssh and run script on remote host and answer expect answer automate

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting, remote, expect

The ssh from server0 to (server1,server2,server3) (no password need to SSH (trust exists between all servers and private key exists on all servers)) but a remote script on server (server1,server2 & server3 ) which starts a service/application needs a password for it to start. I want to be able to use ssh and run a command automatically on remote server. The remote script needs a password or expects a password answer with a password

```
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  servername remotescrip
```

Enter application password to run the script:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then use `expect`:

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh serversuser@server' \
-c 'expect "serverprompt" {send /path/to/your/script\n}' \
-c 'expect "Enter application password to run the script:" {send yourpassword\n}'
```